# I want to format my list differently

Tags: python

I have a list in my program: grid = []

The grid currently holds lines of strings in a format such as:

- qwertyui
- asdfghjk
- zxcvbnml

I want to alter the list so that its format is changed to:

- zaq
- xsw
- cde
- vfr
- bgt
- nhy
- mju
- lki

So in a sense the list would just be turned 90 degrees clockwise. I also want to store the newly formatted strings in a different list called diff_grid[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming grid is a list of the strings you are referring to:

```
>>> grid = ["abc", "def", "xyz"]
```

Try

```
>>> diff_grid = [''.join(i) for i in zip(*grid[::-1])]
>>> diff_grid
['xda', 'yeb', 'zfc']
```

`zip(*grid)` will apply the zip operator on the strings of `grid`.
Note that you have to reverse `grid` `(grid[::-1])` because of the order the zip operation is applied.

Comment: You may want to reverse `grid` first.

Comment: Ya your list comprehension was on point but was backwards. #pro Tigerhawk gotcha

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip()`, and keep in mind that it'll take the first element from each item, then the second, and so on.

```
>>> strings = ['qwertyui', 'asdfghjk', 'zxcvbnml']
>>> for item in zip(*(strings[::-1])):
...     print(item)
...
('z', 'a', 'q')
('x', 's', 'w')
('c', 'd', 'e')
('v', 'f', 'r')
('b', 'g', 't')
('n', 'h', 'y')
('m', 'j', 'u')
('l', 'k', 'i')
```

If you wanted `('q', 'a', 'z')` instead of `('z', 'a', 'q')`, you wouldn't need the `[::-1]` that reverses the `list` of strings.

If you don't want to see the `tuple` structure in the output, you can use `join()` or unpack the `tuple` and use a custom `end` argument:

```
>>> for item in zip(*(strings[::-1])):
...     print(*item, sep='')
...
zaq
xsw
cde
vfr
bgt
nhy
mju
lki
```

Comment: its it possible to print it without all the spaces, commas and apostrophes.